# Setting the range value with VBA when there is an active filter causes values to be out-of-whack

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I've developed some VBA code that will update a listColumn of a listObject by setting the value of the listColumn body data range value to a variant array. I've noticed some excel worksheets this works fine even if there an active filter on the listobject, but annoyingly other clients who use this code will see the data out of whack, the filtered rows will be missed and the variant value are applied directly onto the visible rows. Ie. if the 5th row of the listObject is filtered out, then the 5th value of the variant array is entered into the 6th row (or next available visible row). Since some clients get the correct value into the correct rows and others don't; and both are using Office 365.

Sample code:

```
Sub addValues(pListObject as Excel.ListObject)
    Dim varData as Variant
    Dim iRowCount as Long
    Dim i as Long


    With pListObject
        '' prepare the data to add to the list column
        iRowCount = .ListColumn("Add Data To Column").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        Redim varData(1 to iRowCount , 1 to 1)
        For i = 1 to iRowCount 
            varData(i,1) = i
        Next i
        '' write the values to the list column cells
        .ListColumn("Add Data To Column").DataBodyRange.Value = varData
    End With
End Sub
```